# click on li created from mysql result to show corresponding div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the script that I have been using to allow a click on the dropdown list to show the corresponding div below. I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. The list is generated by mysql query. I have been trying to use "this" in my script, but to no avail (sorry still a noob to jquery). Any suggestions would be great. I left the script tags out on purpose.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#menu['Prosub1']").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#content .container').hide();
            $('#container'.attr('id') ).show();
    });
 });

<div id="Pagecontainer">
    <div class="mainmenu">
    <ul>
        <li id="menubar">Products                     
                 <ul>                       
                    <?php                               
                        foreach ($gbpro->query($gbpro1) as $menu) {
                        echo "<li id=".$menu['Prosub1'].">". $menu['Prosub1'] . "</li>";
                        }
                    ?>       
                 </ul>                    
        </li>                               
      <li>Services                          
                  <ul class="list_items">
                  <?php                             
                        foreach ($gbpro->query($gbserv1) as $menu) {
                        echo "<li data-target=".$menu['Servsub1']." id=".$menu['Servsub1'].">". $menu['Servsub1'] . "</li>";}                           
                   ?>                           
                   </ul>                                              
        </li>                       
      <li>About                                 
                   <ul class="list_items">                        
                   <?php
                        foreach ($gbpro->query($gbabout1) as $menu) {                                                   
                        echo "<li data-target=".$menu['aboutsub']." id=".$menu['aboutsub'].">". $menu['aboutsub'] . "</li>";}                           
                   ?>                               
                   </ul>                    
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>        
 </div>
 <div id="content">
 <div class="container" id="Laptops">
 this is laptops content
 </div>
 <div class="container" id="Tablets">
 this is Tablets content
 </div>
 <div class="container" id="Computers">
 this is computer accessories content
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: please don't post a bunch of server code within your markup when it has no relevance to the problem in browser. Post markup from browser source, since that's what browser and thus script will act on

Comment: not clear what problem is either, or what expectations of your script are

Comment: Sorry guys i'm new to coding(as you can guess). I posted all code so I covered all bases. I am having trouble figuring out the script to allow users to click on a list item and have that <li> show or hide a <div> below. I realize there are mistakes in the html code. My Bad. My biggest issue is targeting the correct <div> due to the fact the list is dynamic. Thanks guys.